# adding overline and underline with padding and alternate color

Tags: html, css

As the title says, I'm looking for help with adding lines on top of a header text with a different color than the text. I tried adding padding, margin and color in the class with overline and underline to no effect. Here is my HTML and CSS:

```css
.lines {
   text-decoration-line: overline underline;
   margin: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-7 justify_text">
      <h2 class="lines">WHO WE ARE</h2>
      <div class="col-md-5">
         <img src="img/pic2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the effect that I want to show:

[image]

Comment: You can add css properties on `lines:before` and `lines:after` elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:after` and `:before` pseudoelemnts to add the lines. Here is an example:

```css
.lines {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.lines:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
}

.lines:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 2px;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 justify_text">
    <h2 class="lines">WHO WE ARE</h2>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <img src="img/pic2.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: worked out well thank you, never realised before and after is a thing in css

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it is to use `border` properties :

```css
h2 {
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 2px solid green;
  border-bottom: 2px solid orange;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>WHO WE ARE</h2>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea with gradient and you will have more flexibility to control colors and sizes:

```css
.lines {
  position: relative;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display:inline-block;
  background:
    linear-gradient(red,red)  top center/100% 2px,
    linear-gradient(blue,blue) bottom center/80% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="lines">WHO WE ARE</h2>
```